# Disable Sound Effects in OSX Lion

Tags: macos, audio

How can I disable that annoying buzzer sound in OSX Lion that I get when, for example, I'm at the terminal and press <kbd>delete</kbd> on an empty line?

I tried to modify the sound settings by unchecking "Play user interface sound effects" but it didn't work.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well, almost. What you want to disable is the "Alert sound", or an audible bell. You can disable it by turning down the Alert volume.

[image]

Comment: 7 seconds faster *and* a screenshot...

Comment: Gotta love [Paintbrush.app](http://paintbrush.sourceforge.net/) :)

Answer (score 0):

Turning off the Alert Volume in Sound Preferences is very easy; the only drawback is that it will silence other system sounds as well, for example file deletion, trash-emptying.

A slightly harder approach is to use an app (for example the free app Audacity) to create an empty or silent sound and export it as Silence.aiff to the /System/Library/Sounds folder. Restart preferences and now you can select "Silence" as your alert sound. Or maybe try googling for silent aiff.

Answer (score 0):

You can also disable this via Terminal.

```
defaults write "Apple Global Domain" com.apple.sound.uiaudio.enabled -int 0
```

Which worked for me on 10.13.6