# How to change or disable sound in end of downloading?

Tags: macos, utorrent

How to disable sound in end of downloading on OSX? I've checked in uTorrent Preferences and I couldn't find it. Either in System Preferences (Sound).

Version: 1.8.6

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disable Sound Effects in OSX Lion](http://superuser.com/questions/332940/disable-sound-effects-in-osx-lion)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Go to notifications in system preferences scroll down to utorrent and uncheck "play sound for notifications"

Comment: Life saver answer. Thanks.